# Variable values disappearing in Java

Tags: java, variables, physics

I'm making a rudimentary particle simulator in Java. For now, all I've done is make the particles atract each other with an equivalent to the electrical force. This part works fine (or at least as well as you would expect for such a basic model).

However, when I add a few particles, the program loses their values for position, velocity and acceleration, but does not lose other data (like, for example, their ID number). This does not always happens with the same amount of particles. Sometimes it happens when I add the fourth, fifth, second or third particle, but never with the first one. It always happens when I click to add a particle, and after it fails, I can no longer add anything (which is odd), and the particles don't move anymore (as you would expect, being their velocities and accelerations 0).

I am storing the particles in an ArrayList. The array does not lose the data (I've checked, the objects are in there, and I can even call their toString() method and retrieve their ID). The problem seems to be related to synchronization (given that it doesn't always happen at the same moment, it seems to be a bit random), but I can't figure out what it is.

I leave all the relevant code below.

```
    public class Scene implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

    public static ArrayList<Particle> particleArray = new ArrayList<Particle>();

    public static Object particleLock = new Object();

    public void update() {

        synchronized(particleLock) {
            for(Particle particle: particleArray) {
                double resultX = 0;
                double resultY = 0;

                for(int i = 0; i<particleArray.size(); i++) {
                    if(i != particleArray.indexOf(particle)) {
                        double[] result = PhysicsEngine.applyElectircalForce(particle, particleArray.get(i));
                        resultX += result[0];
                        resultY += result[1];
                    }
                }

                particle.netForceX = resultX;
                particle.netForceY = resultY;

                particle.update();
            }
        }
    }

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int mouseX = e.getX();
        int mouseY = e.getY();
        boolean positive = true;

        if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            positive = true;
        } else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
            positive = false;
        }


        synchronized(particleLock){
            particleArray.add(new Particle(mouseX, mouseY, positive));
            System.out.println("New particle added at " + mouseX + ", " + mouseY);
        }
    }
}

public class Particle{

public double x;
    public double y;

    public Point2D position;

    public double velX;
    public double velY;

    public double acX;
    public double acY;

    private Color particleColor;
    private int radius = 10;


    // PHYSICS
    public double mass;
    public double charge;
    public double netForceX;
    public double netForceY;

    private boolean positive;

public Particle(double x, double y, boolean positive) {
        this.x = x - radius;
        this.y = y - radius;

        this.velX = 3;
        this.velY = 2;

        this.acX = 0;
        this.acY = 0;

        this.mass = 100;
        this.positive = positive;

        if(positive) {
            this.charge = defaultCharge;
        } else {
            this.charge = defaultCharge*(-1);
        }

        this.position = new Point2D.Double(x, y);

        particleColor = Color.WHITE;
}

public void update() {

        acX = netForceX / mass;
        acY = netForceY / mass;

        velX += acX;
        velY += acY;

        if(x<=0 || x>=Simulation.WIDTH - 23){
            velX = velX * -1;
            x+= velX;
        }

        if(y<=0 || y>=Simulation.HEIGHT - 35){
            velY = velY * -1;
            y+= velY;
        }

        synchronized(Scene.particleLock) {
            for(Particle otherPart: Scene.particleArray) {

                if(otherPart.equals(this)) {
                    continue;
                }

                double distance = otherPart.position.distance(position);


                if(distance <= radius + otherPart.radius) {
                    //aplicar lo que sé de choques de alguna manera
                }
            }
        }

        x+= velX;
        y+= velY;

        position.setLocation(x, y);
    }
}

public class PhysicsEngine {

    static double electricalConstant = 100000;

    public static double[] applyElectircalForce(Particle thisPart, Particle otherPart) {

        double distance = otherPart.position.distance(thisPart.position);

        double angle = Math.asin(Math.abs(thisPart.y - otherPart.y)/distance);

        double force = (electricalConstant * thisPart.charge * otherPart.charge)/Math.pow(distance, 2);

        double forceX = force * Math.cos(angle);
        double forceY = force * Math.sin(angle);

        if(otherPart.x < thisPart.x) {
            forceX = forceX*(-1);
        }

        if(otherPart.y < thisPart.y) {
            forceY = forceY*(-1);
        }

        double[] result = {forceX, forceY};

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is nothing to be synchronized. why are you synchronizing particleLock ? synchronization is playing no role here. you are syncronizing particleLock  but you are not using any data from this object. what is the purpose of particleLock ?

Comment: @hhafeez Obviously, he's synchronising so that he's not adding to the array at the same time as he's iterating through it, thus removing the risk of a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: But he is not synchronizing the arrya which is the actual resource to be synchronized

Comment: okay i see its equivalent but unnessary to define a new object for lock like that

Comment: You should do the force computations without using any angle at all. Or if you must use an angle for some kind of traditional reasons, use the power of the `atan2` function to get the correct position on the unit circle, this also avoids the singularities when the argument of `asin` is close to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem with synchronization when I was working on an android project, try declaring particleArray volatile so that the compiler knows that particleArray will be changed on other or multiple threads. If that does not work I would suggest using a queue to push changes to the particle array from different threads and then pulling the intended changes to the array list in the update method to update your particle array list. In my experience changing values directly between different threads almost always causes problems.

Comment: I don't see any thread involvement in the code but if there are then definitely array should be declared volatile

Comment: thanks! I tried declaring it volatile but didn't work. I'm not sure I know how to do what you are describing.

Comment: @NicolasMartorell what variable you made volatile?